# real-time normalization of sensor data

Tags: python, time-series, numpy-ndarray, normalization, scaling

I am trying to normalize my sensor data set. I would get prefect results if I get the min and max values of my data set.

```
(sensor-sensor.min())/(sensor.max()-sensor.min())
```

However, my sensor data is real-time and it would not be possible to have the min and max values of the data set.
I haven't had much luck finding a pre-existing algorithm (in python) for this, but perhaps I'm just not looking in the right places. Does anyone know of one? Or have any ideas?

Comment: How about normalizing it using min and max of the data received so far? The accuracy will get better over time. You can also normalize it using the range of a sensor, i.e some sensors read data as integer from range [0, 1023].

Comment: I have already tried this method, the range of the sensor value is changing every time ....